# Euler3: Floating point exception core dumped

Tags: c, gcc

I am executing the following program in C and am getting an error: **Floating Point Exception (core dumped).** I removed the zero division error I had before and I am kinda stuck here. Thanks in advance for any pointers.

```
void main()
{
    int i=0;
    long long int num=600851475143;

    for(i=1;i<num/2;i++)
    {
        if((num%i)==0)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<i/2;j++)
            {
                if((i%j)!=0)
                    printf("%d, ",i);
                else break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really see how you can get a floating point exception in code that doesn't have *any* floating point numbers of arithmetic? Is the code you show us the *actual* code you run?

Comment: Thats the code. I am just copy pasting the same

Comment: Tried changing the data type of num from "long long int" to "long int" with no change in the error message

Comment: `i` is becoming 0 at some point because of integer wrap around and then you get a "division by 0" error.

Answer (score 1):

A significant thing you can do is

- Make `long long int num=600851475143LL;`. That `LL` suffix ensures that it is not of type `int`.
- The for loop indexing variables should be `long long` too.

These two changes will make sure there won't be case of overflow which would lead to undefined behavior.

And also make sure in any case you don't hit division by `0` (Also make sure you are using `%` correctly with correct operands). Use break point when the code breaks. That will help you solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Used limits.h and small changes to solve the issue. My Code currently:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    long long int res=0, i=2;
    long long int num=600851475143;

    while (num!=1) {

        if (num%i==0) {

            while (num%i==0) {
                printf ("%lld\t", i);
                num/=i;
            }

            res=i;
        }

        i++;
     }

    printf ("\n\nThe largest prime factor is : %lld\n\n", res);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need `#include <limits.h>` here.